# Is there a way to add, when build is finished, a link to a file location

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins job that runs a build. If build finishes sucessfully, it create a folder in the network with the installer package (it is not located in Job's workspace). Is there a away to add a link to this installer package folder/file?

Comment: Where are you trying to add a link from?

Comment: It is related to the job I'm running and should appear only when job is finished.